# Grey-out (disable) HTML textarea when checkbox is ticked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I don't really know much Javascript yet, I was hoping somebody could help me understand how to solve my problem:

My HTML form has a `checkbox` and then a `textarea`:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" />
<textarea name="details"></textarea>
</form>
```

I want it so that the `textarea` gets disabled when the `checkbox` is ticked so that the user cannot click it and enter text.

I've had a look here and on google, I couldn't find any clear examples of how to do it.

I'm guessing this can be done in Javascript, but I'm feeling a bit out of my depth. Can somebody explain to me how to do this, preferably without using a third party library?

Comment: When textarea is disable? I am unclear about it?

Comment: Hi, I edited the question. Sorry it wasn't so clear.

Comment: do you mean when checkbox is checked, textarea is enabled?

Comment: O silly me. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked)"/>
<textarea name="details" id="tb1"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
function toggleDisabled(_checked) {
    document.getElementById('tb1').disabled = _checked ? true : false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How does the `_checked` value get passed to the function?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is when you mark the checkbox, just add the attribute disabled="disabled" in the textarea.

Checkout the jsfiddle I have added

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Lg4/

Answer (score 0):

This extremely easy to do with jQuery. Everyone uses jQuery, so should you ;-).

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="detailsgiven" />
    <textarea name="details" id="details"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#detailsgiven").change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {                
            $("#details").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#details").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('textarea').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" onclick="document.getElementById('t').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');" />
<textarea id="t" name="details"></textarea>
</form>
```

Notice how `onclick` event of checkbox is used to execute some javascript code.

if you give your html elements ids, you can access the elements in javascripts through `getElementById` method of javascript DOM (document object model).

And once you have the element, you can set/get it's attributes, do whole lot of things.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot of sense. You don't have to put the Javascript code inside `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding to your requirement. At first, textarea is disabled. When detailsgiven checkbox is checked, textarea is enabled and checkbox is disabled so that he cannot changed. Try like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function valueChanged()
{
    var element1 = document.getElementById("detailsgiven");
    var element2 = document.getElementById("details");
    if(element1.checked)
    {
        element2.disabled=false;
        element1.disabled="disabled";
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="detailsgiven" id="detailsgiven" onchange="valueChanged()"/>
    <textarea name="details" id="details" disabled="true"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```